# Cython with Numpy / AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Handler'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, cython

I want to use Numpy in Cython, but encountered the following error. This error happens even if I run the simple code, so it should be an issue related to importing Numpy.

My environment:

- OS X Yosemite
- Python 3.4.3

setup.py:

```
import numpy as np
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
        name = 'my_code',
        ext_modules = cythonize('my_code.pyx'),
        include_path = [numpy.get_include()]
)
```

my_code.pyx:

```
cimport numpy as np

cdef int a
```

Execute in Terminal:

```
$ python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 253, in <module>
    class _CapturingHandler(logging.Handler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Handler'
```

Comment: Does `numpy` by itself work?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes. If I launch Python on Terminal, I can import Numpy. (Or I can also use it on Jupyter Notebook)

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I ran into this because I had a very similar issue with numpy.

It turns out I had a directory named `logging` as a sibling of the script I was trying to run. So the problem was a simple naming collision between my local project folder and the logging module numpy expected to find. Renaming the project `logging` folder solved the issue for me.

Looking at OP's error message, I suspect this was the case for them as well.